# Materialize select element scrolling using javascript

Tags: materialize

I am using materialize framework

I am not getting the scroll bar when i add more option tag to my select...it beyond the screen.

Please help .

thanks in advance

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the overflow of y on the dropdown-content class to auto.

```
.dropdown-content {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use version 0.100.2.

Change line 5443 for **overflow-y: auto !important**.

This solution resolved my problems.